# According to this code, how could a FutureTask be cancelled if the returned Future<V> is confined in instance?

Tags: java, multithreading, future

Here's the code:

```
public class Memoizer<A, V> implements Computable<A, V> {
    private final ConcurrentMap<A, Future<V>> cache
        = new ConcurrentHashMap<A, Future<V>>();
    private final Computable<A, V> c;
    public Memoizer(Computable<A, V> c) { this.c = c; }
    public V compute(final A arg) throws InterruptedException {
        while (true) {
            Future<V> f = cache.get(arg);
            if (f == null) {
                Callable<V> eval = new Callable<V>() {
                    public V call() throws InterruptedException {
                        return c.compute(arg);
                    }
                };
                FutureTask<V> ft = new FutureTask<V>(eval);
                f = cache.putIfAbsent(arg, ft);
                if (f == null) { f = ft; ft.run(); }
            }
            try {
                return f.get();
            } catch (CancellationException e) {    <-- line 1
                cache.remove(arg, f);
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                throw launderThrowable(e.getCause());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`line 1` catches the `CancellationException`, while the `Future<V> f` is confined in the method so that I think nobody could invoke `f.cancel()` to cancel the FutureTask `ft`.

So is `line 1` really necessary?

Answer (score 1):

> […] the `Future<V> f` is confined in the method […]

This is not actually true. `f` is stored as a value inside the `cache` field, whose purpose is to ensure that only any given computation is only performed once (even if multiple threads all want the result).

That said, if what you've posted is the entirety of the class definition, and the class is defined in its own file (as opposed to being a nested class whose private fields are visible to some code outside itself), and no reflection is being used, then — you're right, that exception should never be raised; and since it's not a checked exception, the code doesn't actually need to acknowledge it at all.